# Automaticlly open app when notification recived from fcm (without clicking it) flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want when i recived and notification from FCM so my app is automatically open and redirect with a  specific screen

FCM is implemented and perfectly working fine when the application is running or in the background. When a notification received on and i taped on it , the application moves to the relevant screen and performs the task.

but i want without tap my app is open

```
//handle tap on notification when app is in background or terminated
  Future<void> setupInteractMessage(BuildContext context) async {
    // when app is terminated
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
      handleMessage(context, initialMessage);
    }

    //when app ins background
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      handleMessage(context, event);
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      handleMessage(context, event);
    });


  }

 void handleMessage(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) {
    print('emergency');
    if (message.data['type'] == 'emergency') {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TimerView()));
    }
  }

  Future forgroundMessage() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }
```